# Add cancel button to Inline Entity Form/Entity Browser dialog

Tags: 9

We're using Inline Entity Form to give users the ability to create new nodes of a different content type and add them to the being edited/created node. When using one of the IEF widgets, there's a cancel button... but if I launch the inline form in a modal using Entity Browser there's no cancel button, just the close modal icon in the upper right corner. I'm trying to get a cancel button back into the form. I've been trying to use form_alter in my theme file, but the cancel button I create doesn't work. I tried to copy over the attributes from the Cancel button the IEF has, but it and its submit button seem to be wired up/coded differently the the variation that appears when rendering the form in a modal via the Entity Browser module.